# Dependency Injection with Generic Interface and Inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, dependency-injection, composition

I recently thought about a case where i can build the abstractions of news importer into the .NET DI Contianer.

This is my example Case.

This class represents a news source.

```
public abstract class Source {
   public Guid Id {get; set;}
}
```

This concrete Source is a Rss Feed.

```
public class RssFeed: Source {
   public string Url {get; set;}
}
```

Now i have a generic interface for an importer of some source.

```
public interface ISourceImporter<TSource> where TSource:  Source {
Task IEnumerable<Post> ImportAsync(TSource source)
}
```

And a concrete Implementation for the RssFeed Sorce

```
public class RssFeedImporter: ISourceImporter<RssFeed> {
}
```

Register the Service into the DI Container

```
services.AddSingleton<ISourceImporter<RssFeed>, RssFeedImporter>()
```

So the Main problem ooccurs at the usage of the service throug the ServiceProvider. I my Command i want to abstract the concrete type of my source like this.

```
public Task ImportCommand(Source source) {
   ISourceImporter<Source> importer = (ISourceImport<Source>)serviceProvider
           .GetRequiredService(typeof(ISourceImporter<>).MakeGenericType(source.GetType()))

   var posts = await importer.ImportAsync(source);
}
```

Is there a way to build that abstraction with the .NET Dependency Container? Maybe is my structure not suitable for this?
I read an [article](https://www.jimmybogard.com/crossing-the-generics-divide/) about open generics but this gives me a circular dependency  when building the DI Container.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post the exception. Without it it's hard to understand what the problem is. Generic DI works out of the box, eg `services.AddSingleton<IMyThingInterface<T>, MyThingConcrete<T>>();` will register a concrete but still generic implementation of the generic interface. That's how eg `ILogger<T>` works.

Answer (score 1):

If the solution can't be solved by turning `ImportCommand(Source)` into an `ImportCommand<TSource>(TSource source) where TSource : Source`, you will have resort to using Reflection.

The easiest way (least amount of code) is by making use of the `dynamic` keyword:

```cs
public async Task ImportCommand(Source source)
{
   Type importerType = typeof(ISourceImporter<>).MakeGenericType(source.GetType());
   dynamic importer = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(importerType);
   await importer.ImportAsync(source);
)
```

But note the following:

- The call to `ImportAsync` will fail when you refactor the interface. That, however, is easily solved by writing a unit test for `ImportCommand`.
- The call to `ImportAsync` will fail when the `ISourceImporter<T>` implementation is internal, even if the interface is public.